# Relax Security for a Spring Data REST Projection

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a User class and I want to authorize access such that only a user gets to see what he is entitled to.

This was easily achievable using Spring Security in conjunction with Spring Data Rest where in JPA Repository I did below -

```
public interface UserRepository extends JPARepository<User,Integer> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('LOGGED_IN') and principal.user.id == #id")
    User findOne(@Param("id") Integer id);

}
```

In this way, a user when visits to Spring Data REST scaffolded URLs like -

```
/users/{id}
/users/{id}/userPosts
```

Only those logged in with {id} get to see these and everyone else gets 401 like I would have wanted.

My problem is that I have one of Projections which is a public view of each user and I am crating it using Spring Data Rest projections as below which I want to be accessible for every {id}

```
@Projection(name = "details", types = User.class)
public interface UserDetailsProjection {
..
}
```

So, `/users/{id1}?projection=details`  as well as  `/users/{id2}?projection=details` should give 200 OK and show data even though user is logged in by **`{id1}`**

I began implementing this by marking projection with @PreAuthorize("permitAll") but that won't work since Repository has harder security check. Can we have this functionality where for a projection we can relax security ?

I am using latest Spring Data Rest and Spring Security distributions

Answer (score 2):

Seems reasonable to add a custom controller for this use-case.

Please also consider:

- Evaluate access in projections using `@Value` annotations
- Add another entity for the same database data but with different field set for read-only operations, e.g. using inheritance (be careful with caching, etc.) - depends on your data storage type
- Modify model to split `User` entity into two different entities (profile, account) since they seem to have different access and possibly even operations
- You can also add a `ResourceProcessor<UserSummaryProjection>` to evaluate access programmatically and replace resource content (projection) with a DTO

Example of **evaluating access in projections** with `@Value` annotations:

```
@Projection(types = User.class, name = "summary")
public interface UserSummaryProjection {
  @Value("#{@userSecurity.canReadEmail(target) ? target.email: null}")
  String getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added spring security code in the data access layer is not a good idea. I would suggest you to add the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to the controller/service method. Since you have a query parameter, `?projection=details`, you can have separate controller/service method for the details projection.

Add following to your details projection method:

```
@RequestMapping("/url", params = {"projection"})
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('LOGGED_IN') and principal.user.id == #id")
```

Comment: I have one problem with this approach that with Spring Data Rest all Controllers and Services are generated by framework and I therefore only have handle to Repository where I can configure security. I have custom URL as well and this solution would be perfectly fitting that. Unless I am totally mistaken, can you please tell me how to secure Spring Data Rest generated URLs like /users/{id} and /users/{id}/userPosts like I mentioned in post without adding these annotations in Repository ?

Comment: Also I doubt If I can add @RequestMapping to Spring data Rest projections ?